# GA report contaioning two paramaters

Tags: google-analytics

Im struggling with creating a report which will show me all pages visited having a certain "page title" and displaying it's origin. I would like to know where pages where accessed from when knowing their page title.

When I set "page title" filter and secondary dimension of "Full referrer" I see a list of page titles instead of page urls having that title.

What is the proper way to get such report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the standard report which allows reporting "only" 2 dimensions and filtering on only the included dimensions

Create a Custom Report which allows reporting on up to 5 dimensions and filtering on dimensions not included in the table

Try this custom report template and adjust the filter to suit
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=CUHZXRU4TruuIigZ8aFgyg

**Note** The Full Referrer and other Acquisition dimensions are Session-scoped and so identify external traffic sources.

If by "origin" you mean internal referrers, you would need to set a hit-scoped custom dimension set to the page's document.referrer and use that